# C# ListBox Selected Item Null Exception

Tags: c#, listbox, nullreferenceexception

The user can click an item in a ListBox as follows:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Clear();
    listBox2.Items.Clear();

    string[] p = 
         Directory.GetFiles(
             textBoxDir.Text, 
             listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(),
             SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (string open in p) 
        ......
}
```

All is fine. However if the user clicks on an empty space in the ListBox, it displays the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException
```

This is because of this line of code:

```
string[] p = 
    Directory.GetFiles(
        textBoxDir.Text, 
        listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(),   
        SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Does anyone have a clever work around? Or suggest an aalternative to my code?

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The workaround is to check for a null value, and exit early.

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItem == null)
{
    return;
}
```

This avoids the nesting introduced by the other answers, which makes the code less readable.

Answer (score 4):

You can check `SelectedIndex` before that line:

```
if(listBox2.SelectedIndex < 0)
    return;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about doing a

```
if(listBox1.SelectedItem != null){
    // ... do your work with listBox1.SelectedItem here
}
```

that should prevent that error from happening.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
{
    string[] p = Directory.GetFiles(textBoxDir.Text, listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(),   SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}
```

Full Code

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
    {    
        textBox2.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();

        string[] p = Directory.GetFiles(textBoxDir.Text, listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string open in p) 
         ...... }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just check first if listbox1.SelectedItem is empty or not prior to calling this line:

```
string[] p = Directory.GetFiles(textBoxDir.Text, listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(),   SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. This is the shortest way i fixed it.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radioButton1.Checked = !radioButton1.Checked;
        string indicadorPais = "Something";
        if (listaPaises.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            indicadorPais = listaPaises.SelectedItem.ToString();
            label1.Text = indicadorPais;

        }
```

As a sidenote. My condition originally was comparing listaPaises.SelectedItem.ToString() != null. This broke because i was casting null to a string. The code im sending works fine.

Answer (score -1):

However none of these allow you to go back in and re-select from the list box.  Still working on that issue - will update.

```
while (user == null) {
    try {
        user = this.lstAdministratorName.SelectedItem.ToString();
    } catch { 
        lstAdministratorName.ClearSelected(); 
        return; 
    }
}
```

Comment: while (user == null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        user = this.lstAdministratorName.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        lstAdministratorName.ClearSelected();
                        return;
                    }
                }

Comment: Sorry new to the forum and haven't figure out how to add code.  It does work though.

Comment: I edited your post with your comment. Consider reading the [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to correctly format post on Stack Overflow.